# Prototype inheritance return value

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

This code sample is derived and tweaked from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

If you see the code, the B.prototype's `doSomething()` method is calling A.protoype's `doSomething()` while applying B's `this` obj. So why is the output of this code returning from B.prototype instead of A.prototype ? may be i am missing something here, but unable to figure out why.

```
function A(a) {
    this.varA = a;
}

// What is the purpose of including varA in the prototype when A.prototype.varA will always be shadowed by
// this.varA, given the definition of function A above?
A.prototype = {
    varA: null, // Shouldn't we strike varA from the prototype as doing nothing?
    // perhaps intended as an optimization to allocate space in hidden classes?
    // https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript#Initializing instance variables
    // would be valid if varA wasn't being initialized uniquely for each instance
    doSomething: function(a) {
        return "DoSomething From A"
    }
}

function B(a, b) {
    A.call(this, a);
    this.varB = b;
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, {
    varB: {
        value: null,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    },
    doSomething: {
        value: function() { // override
            A.prototype.doSomething.apply(this, arguments);
            return "DoSomething From B" // call super
                // ...
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    }
});
B.prototype.constructor = B;

var b = new B();
b.doSomething(7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* calling `A.prototype.doSomething`, you just aren't doing anything with the value returned from the method on the prototype of `A`.

1. `A.prototype.doSomething.apply(this, arguments);` returns "DoSomething from A" and that value is discarded
2. `return "DoSomething from B"` is returned as the return value of `b.doSomething(7)`.

Change your `return`s to `console.log`s and you'll see it works just like you expect, you'll get the `A` message, then the `B` message.